# Python/Django - How to annotate a QuerySet with a value determined by another query

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Django 1.11, python 2.7, postgresql

I have a set of models that look like this:

```
class Book(Model):
    released_at=DateTimeField()

class BookPrice(Model):
    price = DecimalField()
    created_at = DateTimeField()
```

Assuming multiple entries for Book and BookPrice (created at different points in time), I want to get a QuerySet of `Book` annotated with the `BookPrice.price` value that was current at the time the Book was released.  Something like:

```
books = Book.objects.annotate(
            old_price=Subquery(BookPrice.objects.filter(
                          created_at__lt=OuterRef('released_at')
                          )
                          .order_by('created_at')
                          .last()
                          .price
                      )
           )
```

When I try something like this, I get an error: `This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

I could get the data with a for loop easily enough, but I'm trying to prepare a large chunk of data for a CSV download and I don't want to iterate through every book if I can help it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing `.last().price`. This code resolves (executes) the query and tries to get a python object. Hence the error you are getting as the query you are trying to execute contains an `OuterRef`, therefore it cannot be executed.

You should transform your query into something like the following:

```
last_price_before_release_query = BookPrice.objects.filter(created_at__lt=OuterRef('released_at')).order_by('-created_at').values('price') # Note the reversed ordering 
books = Book.objects.annotate(old_price=Subquery(last_price_before_release_query[:1]))
```

You can get more information [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#limiting-the-subquery-to-a-single-row).